# What is OpenGL's relationship with the DRM

Tags: linux-kernel, graphics, opengl

I recently got into OpenGL and I was researching on how opengl can either render directly or indirectly using the X window system.

What I understood was that, in order to render directly it uses something known as the DRI (Direct Rendering Infrastructure). The DRI then makes use of the DRM (Direct Rendering Manager) to access the hardware directly.. (I don't know if I got that right)

Why do we even need OpenGL, why can't we access the hardware directly using the DRM?

Comment: so, since this is really, just from the wording of it, mostly a duplicate of the question you link to, *could you explain what you don't understand about the answer given*. Chances are, our answer to your question here (if we don't happen to close your question as duplicate) would be very similar to the answer over there, and that would not help you. So, what's the part about the answer there that makes no sense to you?

Comment: Why do we need opengl then? why can't we create applications by accessing the DRM directly since it basically can access the hardware directly

Comment: Can you **edit** your post to be about OpenGL, if this is what it's about? And what do you *think* that OpenGL is?

Comment: can you answer the question now?

Comment: not really, now I wonder what kind of thing you mean when you say "access the hardware directly using the DRM"; it's a bit unclear what "access" is in that case.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_Manager) the DRM exposes an API for us to use to access the GPU. OpenGL is a specification that allows us to access the GPU as well. So I wanted to know why we even need OpenGL?

Comment: The Wikipedia page you linked to says it is specific to the Linux kernel. OpenGL is a cross-platform, versioned standard. If I wanted to write a game or something, why would I cripple myself by using only the Linux kernel-specific API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**What is OpenGL and what is graphics card?**

OpenGL is high level 3D graphics library.

Although it is used to talk with "graphics card", or rather a GPU, it abstracts many differences between the many 3D capable cards into much simpler and more coherent OpenGL "concept space". OpenGL does not care whether computer has PCI, is a SoC, how many control registers card has or any other unimportant hardware details.

Modern OpenGL capable GPU, like from nvidia, ati or in a mobile chipset, is not really "a graphics" card even, per se.

In fact, actual "graphics card" of the modern GPU is like 0.01% of it's circuitry these days.

In reality, modern GPU is very complicated "3D graphics engine". So much that 99.99% of the GPU chip is this engine.

We are not talking about low level primitives like pixels either.

For example, almost all past GPUs (circa '00) had so called "2D blitter" engines, actual physical circuitry, for bitmap transfer ie ["blitting"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blitter).

Older consoles like SNES have similar circuitry (to blitter) which could transfer, transform, stretch and rotate an image sprite (in a single step) into framebuffer memory. We tend to call that circuitry "a rotozoomer". Because it was expressed in hardware, SNES could easily do 60fps fluid graphics even while being 8/16-bit computer (naturally number of sprites was limited by a design of a given chip).

Modern GPUs don't even have "2D blitters" or "rotozoomers" anymore, as when you draw 3D quad polygon composed from 2 traingles in specifically configured ortographic projection, the GPU's 3D engine can essentially work as blitter/rotozoomer of old, but because it is being processed by actual 3D circuitry, you have incredible amount of flexibility: fragment shaders, vertex shaders, Z-buffer, stencil buffer, vertex arrays etc. Think of it as hyper-duper-rotozoomer on steroids.

In fact, most GPUs are so advanced these days, that they can draw, texture and shade complex 3D models in insane number of instances on screen completely autonomously - i.e. modern GPUs draw whole secenes on their own!

They are, in fact, their own computers within computers. Think about it. The GPU actually understands(!) model data (edges lists, polygons/triangle lists, textures, transformation matrices, and these days even tensors), model transformations, perspective projection transformations and so on.

Even more, all of this is "programmable"(!), i.e. you can compose "micro-programs", compile them into card processor(s) instructions and "upload" them (non-permanently) into the card itself.

OpenGL expresses all these operations in a programming language agnostic form. For example it contains fully optimizing shading language compiler not much different from gcc or clang (llvm), but you don't even get to see fragment shader's assembly instructions. There is simply no need.

But at a lower level, a system level, all these model data and shader programs have to get into the card, somehow. You also have to "drive" the card around (ie send commands to it: draw this, draw that, clear screen). Some of these data (like compiled shader programs and model data) come in form of memory blocks/chunks. Other things, like commands, often work through GPU registers, as in CPU.

On PC style computers, with PCI technology, all of this is usually done by mapping the card's register sets and "memory windows" (data transfer holes) from PCI space into processor memory space. But it might be done completely differently in a tablet or a phone (many SoCs don't even have PCI).

Such details are of no interest to you as a graphics programmer.

**Traditional "unix" "graphics"**

Now, traditionally, "unix" (BSDs, Linux, Solaris etc) did not care a zilch about graphics. X11 server was tool designed for that.

In fact in old "unix" systems, there was not even a concept of a display driver: "unix" did not even know, what a graphics card is!

To it and it's kernel it was useless, dead device, draining power, unlike a teletype or a disk drive, about which it knew quite a lot :).

How did X do drawing then, you might ask?

With X, unix system was actually extended (and this extension was really tiny - unlike DRI on modern systems) in a away that allowed it to map PCI memory mentioned above, into the address space of normal usermode process: i.e. X server.

And thus, through this "hole", it was X that actually talked and "drove" the card directly. Think about it for a second - it's kind of microkernel/FUSE like design.

This worked...

... for a time ...

... but it turned out, that this did not work as well as we thought it would.

It was sufficient at the beginning, but as cards and GUIs got more complex, this design did not cope well with load and usage requirements.

The initial design is beautiful:

- crashing X won't crash the system.
- programs ask X to draw, and X arbitrates the drawing among them and drives the hardware directly.
- because communication with X goes over a socket, the drawing works even over the network (so much for memed to death network transparency).

Situation "on the ground" was simple as well:

- graphics cards really were just a few components: framebuffer, character generator, display controller and if it was a fancy card, a blitter.
- applications issued mostly simple commands to draw simple vectorial 2D graphics.
- X is the "knowledge point" of graphics algorithms (today it is a combination of GPU's circuitry and shader code - both live outside of X).

It turned out we need/wanted more...

**Ill effects of usermode X**

First, usermode program driving hardware directly introduced latencies and  all kind of weird issues.

Like, for example, sometimes graphics cards generate interrupts - how do you propagate interrupt from kernel from a device, that it does not care about, into usermode X server process?

Sometimes response to this interrupt has to be instantaneous, but what if Xorg is currently scheduled out and ssh is handling incoming traffic at the moment?

Or another thing: to draw anything, you have to switch from your program's usermode, to kernel mode, to X's usermode and back (latency). In fact, it is even worse, you will see.

Many issues like this started popping up.

Second, X needed it's own drivers to talk to these cards: these were not kernel drivers, but kind of like FUSE-like X drivers for usermode X to talk with hardware. Kinda mess.

Third, slowly but surely, it was discovered that kernel, if it is to stay relevant, needs to know what graphics (if you want to have graphical boot screen, kernel needs to know about graphics modes and monitors etc - some devices like phones don't even have textmode graphics). So kernel started growing it's own drivers anyway - thus at a time, there started to be a duplication of drivers for any card - one for X and other one for the kernel.

Fourth, modern "graphics cards" are not graphics cards anymore - these are intelligent engines that know all kinds of interesting objects: fragment shaders, vertex shaders, textures, vertex buffers, display buffers, displays, monitors ... list is insane.

In modern multitasking unix-like OS there are potentially multiple applications running, at the same time, under different users, on different displays, many using such hardware objects in the card concurrently - ie you need accounting (allocation/deallocation), acces control and so on.

X manages all these objects among applications from user space - but when X crashes, what happens to these objects? They stay allocated on the card, but the system has lost all the accounting information about them. Only way to recover from this is to reset the card hard, so that it forgets everything and starts anew.

Finally think about how X based socket drawing works. Let's say your application wants to draw a 10K vertex 3D model:

1. application has to prepare memory buffer for the model data to be held
2. it has to format the model data into proper format
3. then send it over unix socket (or network, if you are insane) to X
4. X has to prepare memory buffer to receive the data
5. kernel shuffles data over
6. X has to prepare communications with the card
7. X has map it's data into the card (ie "send" it to the card)
8. kernel shuffles data over
9. X has to retrieve result of the operation, pack it and return it over the X socket
10. kernel shuffles data over
11. application has to receive result in message
12. application can look at message received and learns that operation failed

Keep in mind that any of the action above can be pre-empted by anything else in need of servicing or running (audio player, ssh, disk, etc). More over all of this back and forth takes probably longer, than modern OpenGL game can render a frame with million detailed trees in it (latency).

**Modern times: Kernel learns not only to chew bubblegum and walk, but also to paint like Bob Ross too, all at the same time**

Thus two new technologies are introduced: KMS and DRI.

KMS - Kernel ModeSetting - it makes kernel aware of graphics cards and that they have: framebuffers, display links, monitors/displays and resolutions.

DRI - Direct Rendering Infrasturture - it extends the kernel with DRM (Direct Rendering Manager) aware of the fact, that some cards are complex 3D graphics engines that can contain objects: buffers/various memory blocks (framebuffers, models, textures, memory holes for "streaming in" data), shaders and other stuff. It juggles around access rights to them too.

After all, kernel can do the best system object accounting (processes, files, memory maps) in the system. DRM extends this to graphics objects. If X (or anything else using it) crashes, kernel will get the the event and will clean all the process related resources from the card itself. No more object leaks, and hard card resets.

All these interfaces are implemented using syscalls, file descriptors and memory maps, instead of sockets (like with X), and go directly into the kernel when needed. So the latency is greatly reduced, in case of in-memory mapped "holes" almost instantaneous.

Because these are syscalls, and other kernel objects, and not buffers sent over sockets, zero copy data transfers at full hardware speeds can be achieved.

Finally you have to understand, that in case of DRI, it is the drawing application itself (NOT X!) that communicates with cards directly.

That's a reason why it's called "direct".

For example, if you are running X and using DRI application, like something OpenGL based, contents that gets drawn into this window usually goes into card through specific application private codepath over DRI, not over X. X just pretends the window maps to it's position in X display.

Modern OpenGL is built on top of DRI. However DRI is not about drawing...

**Why not use DRI directly? Because what would be the point?**

If you are using OpenGL, you are already using it directly. It's just that in that case it is OpenGL library loads into your process address space that drives DRI.

But for graphics application programmer it makes no sense to bother with DRI, it is simply too low level. DRI deals with system things, like access rights, allocation tracing and cleanup, drawing context switching, commands multiplexing, memory mapping and so on.

There is not much "drawing" going on in DRI. What could a graphics programmer gain from messing with this subsytem? Literally nothing.

Also DRI is strongly unix system specific (all major BSDs use Linux's DRI infrastructure), so it's kinda like Direct3D of unix but at a much lower level, so Direct3D comparison is not really fair, here.

For example, another new API that is using DRI directly is Vulkan. Look at Vulkan code, for how much more complex it is, when compared to same OpenGL code: is is because it allows you to go to much lower level than OpenGL ever did. Yet DRI is at even lower level, and does not deal with "drawing" here either.

Another API that probably uses DRI under the hood, but has nothing to do with 3D graphics and deals with completely orthogonal world of video decoding is VDAPU. Internals of VDAPU are completely disconnected from it's application users: media players.

DRI is directly tied to hardware minutiae of specific cards, and a big part of it DRM and graphics memory managers, lives in kernel and not in application or userland.

It makes no sense for application programmers, even graphics programmers, to reach to DRI level directly, unless they want to do specific system programming tasks (like fixing DRI). If they can do that, they can readily work on open source graphics drivers instead. Or on OpenGL, Vulkan or VDPAU libraries themselves, for that matter.

OpenGL and Vulkan abstract the differences among cards into "thin", cross platform layer, that is expressive more than enough for any task graphics programmers might want to do.

It is of no interest of graphics application programmer on how texture allocation works in some other application running parralel to his, or which texture is bound to specific DRM file descriptor.

All they they care is about driving the card the way they want, by their application.